# Split set in python

Tags: python, set

I have a set of dictionaries with some key-value pairs. I would like to know the most efficient way to split them in halves and then apply some processing on each set. I suppose there exists some one liner out there...

i.e. if I have the dictionaries A,B,C,D, I would like to have the resulting sets: (A,B), (A,C), (A,D) and NOT the remaining sets (C,D),(B,D),(B,C)

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. Could you show, in code, an example of your starting set of dictionaries and the output?

Answer (score 5):

`itertools` and one-liners usually belong in the same sentence:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> i = itertools.product(s[0], s[1:])
>>> list(i)
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D')]
```

Answer (score 1):

may be something like this:

example:

```
In [17]: from itertools import *

In [18]: lis=('a','b','c','d')

In [19]: for x in islice(combinations(lis,2),len(lis)-1):
    print x,
   ....:     
   ....:     
('a', 'b') ('a', 'c') ('a', 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
def foo(l):
    s0 = None
    for i in l:
        if s0 is None: 
            s0=i
            continue
        yield (s0,i)

for k in foo(l):
    print k
```

outputs:

```
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, `itertools` is clearly an overkill:

```
>>> s = 'ABCDE'
>>> [(s[0], x) for x in s[1:]]
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E')]
>>>
```